# Django Key Error: KeyError at 'template.html' request when initiating a form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, stripe-payments

I'm working with Pinax-Stripe library, and I want to create a custom account for the logged in user. [I'm trying to rewrite the CreateCustomAccountView() as a function based view](https://pinax-stripe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/connect/#creating-a-custom-account). The reason for that, is that I don't understand where `CreateBankAccountView` comes from and it's nowhere to be seen [in the GitHub code](https://github.com/pinax/pinax-stripe/blob/master/pinax/stripe/forms.py).

So for simplicity, I have the following form:

```
class Form(DynamicForm):
    # some form fields
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         self.request = kwargs.pop("request")
```

**views.py**

```
def view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Form(request.POST)
    else:
        form = Form()
    return render(request, 'dashboard/template.html', {'form': form})
```

I do have `request` in my template processor. I'm not sure why this happens and how it's possible to instantiate an empty form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your form pops `request` without a default,

```
     self.request = kwargs.pop("request")
```

you must pass the request to the form. For example:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = Form(request.POST, request=request)
else:
    form = Form(request=request)
```

Comment: Thanks, can you explain why this would work for `FormView` but not function based view?

Comment: The formview passes `request` in the form kwargs: `form_kwargs['request'] = self.request`. If it didn't, you'd get the same `KeyError`.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you see with the class based view is legit and I guess that developer suddenly overlooked that part of the code.
If you still want to use class-based view try to replace:

```
form_kwargs = super(
        CreateBankAccountView, self
    ).get_form_kwargs(
        *args, **kwargs
    )
```

With:

```
form_kwargs = super(CreateCustomAccountView, self).get_form_kwargs()
```

The class is `CreateCustomAccountView`, and `get_form_kwargs()` takes no arguments.

Comment: Good spot. I've opened a pull request [#561](https://github.com/pinax/pinax-stripe/pull/561) to update the docs.